# Spinner with ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> doesn't display

Tags: android

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinAdapterHrs;
char[] charArrayHours =    new char[]{'0','1','2'};
CharSequence[] charSeqArrayHrs =
        new String[]{ charArrayHours.toString() };
spinnerLeftHrs = new Spinner( this );
spinnerLeftHrs.setSelection( startLeftHrs );
spinnerLeftHrs.setPrompt( "prompt" );
spinnerLeftHrs.setOnItemSelectedListener( this );
spinAdapterHrs = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>
        ( this,
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
          charSeqArrayHrs );
spinnerLeftHrs.setAdapter( spinAdapterHrs );
```

This compiles okay and doesn't crash, but the root of the Spinner
has a text/prompt of [C@4 which when selected shows an overlapping
box with the full [C@417ca5a0.
It does not show the usual Spinner lines.

I had it working with Integers but wanted to save CPU time on my rotten Samsung Galaxy Ace II x; and it is a realtime app with conversions running just-about all the time (as far as the user is concerned at least).

It's a recent Android sdk but the API target is 15.

The environment is Ant under win 10 using TextPad.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Are you saying that instead of '1', for example, the spinner item shows '[C@417ca5a0'? If so, do you think it could be an encoding issue?

Comment: If those values are static, use entries attribute in the spinner tag in the layout and pass the value from string.xml

Comment: `charArrayHours.toString()` what do you think this does?

Answer (score 0):

Why you have converted char array to string??(this is the problem)

You need to loop through elements of char array and store 1 by 1 in String array.

Example

```
for(int i=0;i<charArrayHours.length;i++)
{
charSeqArrayHrs[i]=charArrayHours[i];
}
```

Comment: CCActivity.java:592: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to CharSequence
        [javac]             charSeqArrayHrs[i] = charArrayHours[i];
        [javac]                                                ^
    But thanks for the reply, it's got me moving again (I was really having problems with this thing).

Comment: Ok then instead of charsequence use string array. And you can get string from char value using String.valueOf(char_value);

Comment: First I'm going to try an array of Characters, altho I'm pretty sure I've done it before when it didn't work; I'm hoping you'll help with that!  But I really want to avoid conversions -- I plan on moving the chars (or maybe Characters) to the TextViews manually instead of using setText() and I decrement the times like: '2'-1.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinAdapterHrs;  
        spinAdapterHrs = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>  
            ( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, charArrayHrs );  
    CCActivity.java:636: error: no suitable constructor found for   ArrayAdapter(CCActivity,int,Character[])

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of those characters you are seeing you are probably assigning the object reference of each string to the items in the list of the spinner.

Try creating a single character in memory and assign it to the spinner at the first value.

Then if that works then you know it's your array that is not set up correctly.

I don't think encoding would cause that specific character sequence to populate the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
Character[] charArrayHrs = new Character[]{ '0','1','2' };
ArrayAdapter<Character> spinAdapterCharHrs = 
    new ArrayAdapter<Character>
        ( this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
        charArrayHrs );
spinnerLeftHrs.setAdapter( spinAdapterCharHrs );

public void onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> inParent,  
                            View inView,    
                            int  inPos,     
    inParent.getItemAtPosition( inPos ) returns a Character = 2.
```